# error message without submitting the form

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I am using yup for validations and everything is working fine. So it is like this:

```
    const HISTORY = useHistory();
    
      const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        Name: "",
        Surname: "",
      });
    
      const handleChange = (inputName) => (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          [inputName]: e.target.value,
        });
      };
    
      const Continue = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = {
          Name: inputs.Name,
          Surname: inputs.Surname,
        };
    
        const isValid = await orderFormValidation.isValid(formData);
        if(isValid) {
          HISTORY.push({ pathname: "/checkout", state: inputs });
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <Form className="instantquote p-3 mb-5">
          <Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
            <Form.Label className="form-subtitle">Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              placeholder="Name"
              name="Name"
              onChange={handleChange("Name")}
              defaultValue={inputs.Name}
            />
            {/* TODO: ERROR MESSAGE */}
          </Form.Group>
          

<Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
            <Form.Label className="form-subtitle">Surname</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              placeholder="Surname"
              name="Surname"
              onChange={handleChange("Surname")}
              defaultValue={inputs.Surname}
            />
            {/* TODO: ERROR MESSAGE */}
          </Form.Group>
          <button className="btn button" onClick={Continue}>
            Details
            <BsArrowRightShort />
          </button>
        </Form>
      );
```

So basically, isValid is coming right. So for example, if one of the fields is empty, it returns false and it doesn't go to the next page which is checkout in our case. So my question is I want to give an error message but I dont know how to do it because I am not submitting the form. Here is my validation also:

```
export const orderFormValidation = yup.object().shape({
  Name: yup
    .string()
    .min(3, "Too Short!")
    .max(5, "Too Long!")
    .required("Name Required"),
Surname: yup
    .string()
    .min(3, "Too Short!")
    .max(5, "Too Long!")
    .required("Surname Required"),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add states to accept the error message like this:

```
 const HISTORY = useHistory();

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    Name: "",
    Surname: "",
  });
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [surName, setSurName] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (inputName) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setInputs({
      ...inputs,
      [inputName]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const nameValidation = yup.object().shape({
    Name: yup
      .string()
      .required("Name Required")
      .min(3, "Too Short!")
      .max(5, "Too Long!"),
  });
  const surNameValidation = yup.object().shape({
    Surname: yup
      .string()
      .required("Surname Required")
      .min(3, "Too Short!")
      .max(5, "Too Long!"),
  });
  const Continue = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = {
      Name: inputs.Name,
      Surname: inputs.Surname,
    };
    const isValidSurName = await surNameValidation.isValid(formData);
    const isValidName = await nameValidation.isValid(formData);
    if (isValidName) {
      setName("");
    } else {
      nameValidation.validate(formData).catch((ex) => {
        setName(ex.message);
      });
    }
    if (isValidSurName) {
      setSurName("");
    } else {
      surNameValidation.validate(formData).catch((ex) => {
        setSurName(ex.message);
      });
    }
    if (isValidName && isValidSurName) {
      HISTORY.push({ pathname: "/checkout", state: inputs });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form className="instantquote p-3 mb-5">
      <Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
        <Form.Label className="form-subtitle">Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          name="Name"
          onChange={handleChange("Name")}
          defaultValue={inputs.Name}
        />
        <p>{name}</p>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
        <Form.Label className="form-subtitle">Surname</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Surname"
          name="Surname"
          onChange={handleChange("Surname")}
          defaultValue={inputs.Surname}
        />
        <p>{surName}</p>
      </Form.Group>
      <button className="btn button" onClick={Continue}>
        Details
      </button>
    </Form>
  );
```

if you have more fields, you should extract the validations to a new component

Comment: thanks but I actually have more input fields actually. So I am not sure if this works for my case. Sorry I should have mentioned about this in my question

Comment: you can make it like this with object state for all the inputs, or maybe I didn't understand your question

Comment: I just edited my question. So basically, I need an error message in the place where it writes TODO: ERROR MESSAGE. And I want to show 'Name Required' for name for example.

Comment: So I don't get the error message because I don't know how to do it. This is my question actually :)

Comment: I dont get it clearly I think :( is it okay if you edit you answer above?

Comment: Okay, if you can explain me why I need to change the validation, that would be super good also

Comment: Yeah I think I understand

Comment: I didn't understand, have you edited you answer? So the thing is when enter some value, valid doesnt go to true again which means it continues to show the error. The other thing is for example, if I fill name and dont fill surname, it shows the error for both of them.

Comment: So could you tell me other way please :)

Comment: thank you really clear answer. But I have only one question about code. Actually it is more like a review. So I define inputs like this: const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    Name: "",
    Surname: "",
  }); also you set the inputs like this const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [surName, setSurName] = useState("");. so do you think it makes sense to use both of them?

Comment: yes I was just gonna say it actually. So everything is fine. Thanks!!!